# How to read Json file with keys in puppeteer BDD

Tags: javascript, json, automation, puppeteer, bdd

Hello i am new to puppeteer.I have built my basic framework where i want to read data from .json files.How can i achieve this. I tried to use readFile method in my helper class but when i executed the code it throws an error

And I read the file with the "testdata/logindata.json" and "loginForQC" # features/support/step_definitions/loginSteps.js:29
TypeError: page.readFile is not a function
at Object.readJsonFile (/Users/afshanshakoor/projects/Puppeteer/lib/helpers.js:62:20)
at Function.readJsonFileData (/Users/afshanshakoor/projects/Puppeteer/features/support/pages/loginPage.js:35:43)
at Login. (/Users/afshanshakoor/projects/Puppeteer/features/support/step_definitions/loginSteps.js:30:17)

Answer (score 3):

Why not do it the same way you read config values?

```js
const config = require('./config.json');
```

so:

```js
const testDate = require('./testdata/logindata.json');
```

then you can just use it like so:

```js
await page.type('#email', testData.email);
await page.type('#password', testData.password);
```

provided your test data file looks something like this:

```json
{
    "email": "test@test.com",
    "pwd": "secret-pwd"
}
```